# Sacar porcentaje dependiendo de una serie de datos de otras celdas

Tags: excel, condiciones, porcentaje

Tengo esta tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os explico un poco porque es un poco lioso.

Nosotros trabajamos con 2 tipos de comisionado:

1.- Comisión 40% - 30% - 20% (esta fórmula con SI anidado e Y, ya está solucionado) gracias @DjCrazy

2.- En esta opción es donde está lo complicado (para mí), esta opción de comisión engloba un salario fijo de 550€ más un escalado de comisiones, es decir:

2.1 Si el comercial llega a 2500€, su comisión es del 10%

2.2 Si supera 2500€, la comisión es del 10% hasta 2500€, y un 20% del monto restante, explico:

Si hace una producción de 4000€:

- 2500€ al 10% = (250€)
- de 2500€ a 4000€ es decir (4000-2500) = 1500€ al 20% (300€)

su comisión sería de 250+300€= 550€, a lo que abría que sumarle su fijo de 550€, por lo que le sale a cobrar al comercial es 550(fijo) + 550(comisiones)= 1100€

A ver si me podéis echar un cable

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes sacarlo con un SI:

`=550+SI(A2<=2500;0,1*A2;250+0,2*(A2-2500))`